# DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found pyhton pandas excel files merging

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to merge multiple excel files in folder to one using pandas, iam getting above error

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = os.getcwd("C:/Users/SHARAN/Desktop/EXCELFILES/")
files = os.listdir(path)
files
print (files)
files = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
files
df=pd.DaataFrame()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(data)

writer=pd.ExcelWriter ("CosolidateFile.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1")
writer.save()
```

Error Messeage :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\SHARAN\Desktop\ExcelMerge2.py", line 2, in <module>
>     import pandas as pd   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
>     from pandas.core.api import (   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
>     from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1,
> in <module>
>     from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy   File
> "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60,
> in <module>
>     from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in
> <module>
>     from pandas.core.series import Series   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in
> <module>
>     Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in
> _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
>     from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py",
> line 1, in <module>
>     from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in
> <module>
>     **import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The
> specified module could not be found.**
```

Comment: Error indicates it is raised on `import pandas as pd` line, suggesting you may have a faulty pandas installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. I just uninstall Python3.8 and install Anaconda Python(3.7). I don't exactly what the problem is. But I guess 3.8 may have a dependency problem. If you use Python3.8. You can try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an older version

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==0.25.3
```